# Accessing Multiple pages in a User locked excel document

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a budget document in which each department only has access to their particular page - I have that part working - I am having trouble allowing an ADMIN to access all of the pages.
This is what I have as the code for my UserForm so far: (I would like "Scott" to be able to open all of the pages not just "overview")

```
Dim bOK2Use As Boolean

Private Sub btnOK_Click()
Dim bError As Boolean
Dim sSName As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim p As DocumentProperty
Dim bSetIt As Boolean

bOK2Use = False
bError = True
If Len(txtUser.Text) > 0 And Len(txtPass.Text) > 0 Then
    bError = False
    Select Case txtUser.Text
        Case "Scott"
            sSName = "Overview"
            If txtPass.Text <> "act2" Then bError = True
        Case "Chris"
            sSName = "Run Crew"
            If txtPass.Text <> "act2" Then bError = True
        Case Else
            bError = True
    End Select
End If
If bError Then
    MsgBox "Invalid User Name or Password"
Else
    'Set document property
    bSetIt = False
    For Each p In ActiveWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties
        If p.Name = "auth" Then
            p.Value = sSName
            bSetIt = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next p
    If Not bSetIt Then
        ActiveWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties.Add _
          Name:="auth", LinkToContent:=False, _
          Type:=msoPropertyTypeString, Value:=sSName
    End If


    bOK2Use = True
    Unload UserForm1
End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
If Not bOK2Use Then
    ActiveWorkbook.Close (False)
End If
End Sub
```

Thank you!

Comment: that is the user box code - the rest of the sheet code is

   Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    If Sh.Name <> "Main" Then
        If Sh.Name <> ActiveWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties("auth").Value Then
            Sh.Visible = False
            MsgBox "You don't have authorization to view that sheet"
        End If
    End If
End Sub